# Dojo: TypeError: dojo.byId(...).attr is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

Weird, line one works fine but line 3 give me `TypeError: dojo.byId(...).attr is not a function`. There is hidden fields that hold all student  pair that as `<input type="hidden" id="_hidden_studentname_{somestudentid}" value="aStudentName">`, here {somestudentid} only indicate it as student id variable. The purpose of this is try to get a student name by student id.

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId('_studentId_id'), 'onChange', function (val) {
    var studentId=dijit.byId("_studentId_id").attr("value"); // line 1
    var id="_hidden_studentname_"+studentId;
    var studentName=dojo.byId(id).attr("value");             // line 3
    dojo.byId("_student_text").attr("value", studentName);
});
```

So dojo doesn't allow variable put in `dojo.byId()`? I am pretty sure the `<input type="hidden">` with that id does exist....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note how you were using `dijit.byId` in Line 1, but using `dojo.byId` in line 3.  The former returns a widget (which has an `attr` function), wheras `dojo.byId` returns a DOM element, which does not have an `attr` method.

DOM elements can manipulate attributes directly, so you can update the code to use `something.value = 'some other value';`.

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId('_studentId_id'), 'onChange', function (val) {
    var studentId=dijit.byId("_studentId_id").attr("value"); // line 1
    var id="_hidden_studentname_"+studentId;
    var studentName=dojo.byId(id).value;             // line 3
    dojo.byId("_student_text").value =studentName;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that's awesome!! also I use `dojo.html.set(dojo.byId("_student_text"), studentName);` to put student name into div content. thanks again and cheers.